# Helm custom chart installation

Tags: node.js, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, deis

Currently, I have installed the all custom chart components in the ubuntu 22.04 server while installing the package facing below error

$ helm install deis workflow-2.0.0.tgz

```
`W0925 14:26:50.083551   11990 warnings.go:70] unknown field "annotations"
Error: Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field EnvVar.spec.template.spec.containers.env.value of type string`
```

I have tried with updating the deployment file and Service file. After updating the file facing same error

Comment: Can you please provide the deployment file check to see issue it may have ?